# New HDD for old laptop. What's the optimal partitioning scheme?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-xp, sector-size

I have an old Acer Aspire One AOA150. It has a 160Gb HD and 1.5 Ram Gb with two partitions: Recovery (4GB) and XP (154 Gb).
It's physically light and easy to carry. I want to install linux (lubuntu 17) on it and take it everyday to work.
I bought a Toshiba L200 drive and plan to install it.
I have thought of the following partitioning scheme:
(they will be aligned to the Mb due to Advanced Format on the drive)

> Extended
>
> - Swap 5 Gb.
> - / 300 Gb.
> - Home 400 Gb.

Primary XP 300 Gb.

Primary Recovery 4 Gb.

Is this a good partitioning scheme for performance and frequent Linux usage?
What's the better linux tool for proper partition alignment? I have a gparted boot pendrive and a ubuntu boot pendrive.

I will have to prepare the XP boot as well (I intend to keep it without reinstalling). Files might have to be manually copied due to different sector sizes (drive is an Advanced Format drive). Any other way to transfer disk contents despite different sector sizes?

boot.ini will have to be fixed to default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(4)\WINDOWS and ntloader will have to be added maybe from recovery console.

Am I missing something? Any advice/suggestion? Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Additional info: The start of the drive is usually faster

Comment: also it's not a laptop but a 10 year old MBR netbook

Comment: *It's physically light and easy to carry* ... You have never carried a new ultraslim notebook, have you? When compared to those 2008-9 Atom Netbooks they are about half the weight and, for entry level Celeron based models, also about half the price, and with more powerful CPUs by sevral orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

300Gb for / for what?

- 25Gb is more than enough for a desktop to install all the software you need.
- even for a server (mysql defaults to /var/ for its database) I would expect the personal files to set so it will be on another partition.

I myself would do ...

- / 25 Gb
- /home 10 Gb. Don't use this for personal data. See `~./config/users-dirs.dirs` on how to change the default directories.
- remainder to a partition (as an example: /data). Use this for personal data. Set it up with all the directories /home/$USER/ normally has.

Plus points:

- A re-install of your system with keeping your settings: format /, mount /home and /data.
- A re-install of your system without keeping your settings: format /, format /home and mount /data.
- A backup only requires you to copy /data over to a USB disk
- The personal partition can be encrypted if needed.
- And, if wanted, you can use /data/ for all users so you share the same desktop with all users simply by  setting up a "group".

Comment: So for your user directory(ies), you create a directory in /data and a link to /home/$USER?

Comment: what about swap? after or before / ?

Comment: swap is a file nowadays.  @CharlesGreen nope. see the users-dirs.dirs file in ~./config/

Comment: Interesting!  Do you edit /etc/xdg/user-dirs.default, or just edit on a per-user basis?

Comment: well I have 1 user at home so I use the one in /home. At work though we set up our desktops to connect to a share where our directories are. So a notebook that gets stolen has ZERO data but does have a bootable system so you can use it away from the documents.

Comment: K - your system is similar to mine (I have no work these days) so for me, simply a separate home partition would be sufficient.